# Standard deviation for a subset

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation for a variable within a subset. The coding works fine for mean but not sd. I have included sample where data= orf1 came from the subset. Any help?

```
 mean(Stocking.Density2012,na.rm=TRUE,data=orf1)
    [1] 13.72386
    > sd(Stocking.Density2012,na.rm=TRUE,data=orf1)
    Error in sd(Stocking.Density2012, na.rm = TRUE, data = orf1) : 
      unused argument (data = orf1)

 Region Stocking.Density2012    
    1            12 
    8            7  
    2            12 
    8            17 
    1            34 
    3            24 
    1            16 
    2            5  
    1            5  
    4            11 
    1            5  
    3            3  
    7            3  
    5            13 
    1            18 
    4            15 
    2            18 
    1            10 
    6            5  
    1            10 
    5            46 
    1            19 
    3            12 
    1            15 
    6            4  
    1            4  
    7            8  
    1            8  
    8            12
```

Comment: There are no `data` arguments in either of those functions.  You got a result from `mean` because `data = orf1` was ignored when `...` were processed and you probably have `Stocking.Density2012` defined in your workspace.

Comment: When you're asking a question, try and write a reproducible example. I often find that in doing so it shows me where I've gone wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`data` is neither an argument to `mean` nor to `sd`, so `Stocking.Density2012` must be in the enclosing environment.  Perhaps you `attach`ed it.

`mean` doesn't give an error because it has a `...` argument, which `sd` does not.

Comment: thanks @ Richard Scriven @ Matthew Lundberg - just that still learning R. @  MikeRSpencer I have included data sample